# Building a graph from a list of edges

Tags: haskell, data-structures, graph, edges

Given a graph datatype as follows:

```
data Graph = Int :~> [Graph]
infixr :~>
```

and a list of edges like this:

```
edges = [(10,1), (10,5), (1,2), (2,3), (5,6), (5,9), (9,8)]
```

What is the function that will build the graph as follows:

```
result = 10 :~> [ 1 :~> [ 2 :~> 3 :~> [] ] 
                , 5 :~> [ 6 :~> [], 9 :~> 8 :~> [] ]
                ]
```

I'm sure it's right in front of my head, but I'm a bit exhausted and would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Programming when exhausted is not advised.  Get some rest, then come back and post your best attempt.

Comment: Also this is under-specified.  How should it build a graph with cycles, e.g. `edges = [(1,2), (2,1)]`?

Comment: Or even a DAG like `[(1,3), (2,3)]`? You data type models a tree, not a general graph

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments, @luqui and Niklas B. After giving it some more thought, I've realized that this is a rose tree, not a graph at all. I've also figured out generating the tree from the edges. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find the start node: The node appears in the `map fst edges` list but not in the `map snd edges` list. As luqui remarked, you need to think about cases where you don't find such a node (or if you find more than one)
2. Build your tree recursively from this start node. Be careful as you could still have cycles in the graph

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you want, but the `Data.Graph` module of the `containers` library could help.

```
import Data.Graph
bounds = (1,10) 
edges = [(10,1), (10,5), (1,2), (2,3), (5,6), (5,9), (9,8)]

> buildG bounds edges
array (1,10) [(1,[2]),(2,[3]),(3,[]),(4,[]),(5,[9,6]),(6,[]),(7,[]),(8,[]),(9,[8]),(10,[5,1])]
```